# issue with texts alignment when use float

Tags: css

```
<style>
.floatright { float: right;margin: 0 0 10px 10px; }
p {float: left;}
</style>
<img class="floatright" src="computer.png" alt="" width="60" height="60">
<img class="floatright" src="computer.png" alt="" width="60" height="60">
<img class="floatright" src="computer.png" alt="" width="60" height="60">
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
</p>
```

Question:

why the paragraph: `<p>Lorem ipsum...</p>` not show at the same line with imgs? it starts from the line beneath imgs.

Comment: Enclose everything inside a wrapper `div`. Alternatively remove `float:left` from your `p` and include `img` inside the `p`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The solution**

Remove the `float` property for the `p` elements as follow: [demo](http://jsbin.com/ebafoz/1/)

**Explanation**

When setting the `float` property of the `p` element to a value different than `none`, the `p` element will extends to the maximum width if available and  do not accept any other floating element overlap upon its area.

By use the default value (no floating), the `p` element will allow other floating element take over an area and the text will be fill in other gaps.

Answer (score 0):

try this give `width:--%;` P tag or `margin:0;`

http://jsfiddle.net/AZctd/1/

```
.floatright { 
      float: right; 
      margin: 0 0 10px 10px; 
     border:1px solid red;
       }

p {float:left; 
    width:60%;; 
    margin:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Check the JS Fiddle

[image]

I hope this is what you want..

http://jsfiddle.net/arunberti/zzBb4/2/

CSS

```
 .floatright { float: right;
      margin: 0 0 10px 10px; }
    p {float: left;
        width:65%;
         text-align: justify;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the width of your p.

Otherwise, you need to define your html like this....

```
<p><img src="" /><img src="" /><img src="" />your text here</p>
```

Then give float: right to img

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cjM6Y/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the width of `<p>`. It is taking full width of its parent due to which it is dropping in new line below images.

You can try and set the width of `<p>`

Answer (score 0):

just remove `float:left;` from p it will be good